# Corda State Evolution - nullable vs. default properties

Tags: kotlin, corda

In Corda, adding new properties to states (state evolution) requires that new properties are nullable in order to remain backwards compatible with previous versions of the state.

```
data class Version1DummyState(
    override val participants: List<AbstractParty>
) : ContractState

data class Version2DummyState(
    override val participants: List<AbstractParty>,
    val myNewProperty: String? = null
) : ContractState
```

Since Kotlin also supports properties with default values, I'd like to know why state evolution is restricted to properties of **nullable** types only, but not non-nullable properties, provided that those properties have a default value?

```
data class Version2DumyState(
    override val participants: List<AbstractParty>,
    val myNewProperty: String = "Hello, world."
) : ContractState
```

My rationale for asking this came from looking at the implicit upgrade sample, in which the obligation state is upgraded to allow the obligor to default on their obligation. `true` and `false` accurately represent whether the obligor has defaulted, but `null` does not. The ability to upgrade with a default value of `false` seems more natural than using a nullable field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can make that work by marking the constructor with `@JvmOverloads` like this:

```
data class DummyState @JvmOverloads constructor(
    override val participants: List<AbstractParty>,
    val myNewProperty: String = "blah"
) : ContractState
```

(don't put version numbers into state class names)

The `@JvmOverloads` makes the "old" constructors visible to the deserialisation engine for matching.

But, it's probably better to be explicit here with a line of code like:

`val inDefault: Boolean get() = myNewProperty ?: false`

or

`fun priceOr(default: Amount<Currency> = 0.USD) get() = price ?: default`

if you really want this.

Backwards compatibility and default values need to be treated quite carefully. A common mistake is to use a default value of zero/empty string/false for newly introduced fields, even when those values are semantically meaningful to the app. That is, knowing that the old message didn't specify something is valuable information that shouldn't be lost or replaced with fragile sentinel values. Consider the new field "price". Prices can't be negative, so perhaps a developer sets a default value of zero. But pricing something as free is a meaningful thing to do - maybe not in today's business scenario, but perhaps tomorrow? Now you have a problem.

Kotlin's type system and syntax is very good at dealing with missing values. It's so easy to substitute a default at the use-site using the `?:` operator, I'd be worried about establishing a convention of always supplying a default at the construction site that junior devs follow without being aware of the potential consequences. Explicitly exposing the fact that a default may be substituted forces people to think about whether that's really logical.

Comment: (don't put version numbers into state class names) - we should version by package name, right?

Comment: I think using a well defined set of constant objects and forcing one of them as default value if no real value is known at object initialization is safer than null.

For example a set of three objects:
 [ NEEDS_UPDATE, NEEDS_UPDATE_RAISE_ON_GET, DOES_NOT_APPLY] will allows to create safer getters that can make sensible decisions about when it's appropriate to abort or continue when requesting for an un-initalized value after state evolution.